# Restructuring dataframe from multiple columns of factors to one column containing factors

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

Hello my dataframe currently looks like this:

```
Clone ID    Sequence    Factor_1    Factor_2    Factor_3

clonename   seq_data       1            5          4

clonename2  seq_data2      2            1          3
```

How to restructure dataframe efficiently so that:

```
Clone ID    Sequence    Factor    Factor_population

clonename   seq_data   Factor_1          1

clonename   seq_data   Factor_2          5

...

clonename2  seq_data2  Factor_3          3
```

*edited the table format for clarity. My first question on StackOverflow and I tried my best to present the question clearly so apologies for those kind enough to try help solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `gather` function from the [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr). `starts_with` is a function from [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) that can select the columns start with a string.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  gather(Factor, Factor_population, starts_with("Factor_"))

dat2
#     Clone.ID  Sequence   Factor Factor_population
# 1  clonename  seq_data Factor_1                 1
# 2 clonename2 seq_data2 Factor_1                 2
# 3  clonename  seq_data Factor_2                 5
# 4 clonename2 seq_data2 Factor_2                 1
# 5  clonename  seq_data Factor_3                 4
# 6 clonename2 seq_data2 Factor_3                 3
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "'Clone ID'    Sequence    Factor_1    Factor_2    Factor_3

clonename   seq_data       1            5          4

clonename2  seq_data2      2            1          3",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and also link to the other solutions you provided! I didn't know the type of data I was dealing with was in the "wide" format. Learned a lot!